# variable for all classes objective c

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, global-variables

I need to make a variable that will be available in every class in the project. I'm setting the variable's value in classA and I need to post it in database in classB. How can I declare this kind of variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the variable in `NSUserDefaults` for the App.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// Get user preference

NSString * myVar=[defaults objectForKey:@"myVar"];
//Get the object stored in myVar

[defaults setObject:myObject forKey:@"myVar"];
//Save new object in var

[defaults synchronize];
//Synchronize changes
```